# EnterFrame listener that rotates sprite KILLS my framerate?

Tags: actionscript-3, listener, frame-rate

Well, I'm not quite a newbie, and not nearly an expert, but I find this very strange. I have a class that creates an array of images and rotates through them in an ENTER_FRAME listener function, *a la animated gif*.
Fine.
I added another ENTER_FRAME listener that rotates the object in increments of .5 degrees until it reaches 23.5 degrees, which it does, but my frameRate slows to a crawl.
Bad!
At one time I put a getTimer() device into the first listener to measure how fast it is being called, and I saw about 20ms *without* the rotation listener, and 200-250ms when the rotation listener was active.
Also of note, when the rotation listener reaches 23.5 degrees, and turns itself off, the calling of the frameAdvance listener stays the same (terribly slow).

Functions in my class:

```
    private function drawThis():void {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, wait4images);            
        for (var i:int = 0; i < shapeLoader.ShapeArr.length; i++) {
            addChild(shapeLoader.ShapeArr[i]);
        }

        //stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, rotateme);
             //like this, it works quickly!

        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, rotateme);
             //like this, it is very slow!

        graphics.lineStyle(2,0xff0000)
        graphics.moveTo(0, -this.width / 2);
        graphics.lineTo(0, this.width / 2);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameAdvance,false,0,true);
    }

    private function rotateme(e:Event):void{
        this.rotation += .5;
        if (this.rotation == 23.5) {
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, rotateme);
        }
    }

    private function frameAdvance(e:Event):void {
        frameNo += 1;   
        addChild(shapeLoader.ShapeArr[frameNo]);
        if (frameNo == 23) {
            frameNo = 0;
        }
    }
```

Any ideas/explainations/solutions for this problem out there?

Comment: If you only desire to rotate an image like a 'loading' gif I suggest using a Tween library instead. They don't require to be in an ENTER_FRAME event and are not process intensive. [GTween is free and opensource](https://github.com/gskinner/GTween)

Comment: @Mr.Phantom - Tweening engines use ENTER_FRAME under the hood.  They do however abstract out all the potential memory leaks which is probably the problem here.

Comment: @Chowzen - try `this.cacheAsBitmap = true;` in your `drawThis` function.  Rotation can be quite expensive, but I would think your frameAdvance method would be the one taxing the system.

Comment: do you remove the `frameAdvance` listener after all the images are added?

Comment: @www0z0k I do. I specifically left this line: *removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, wait4images); * in the code I posted to alleviate potential fears that I left dangling listeners.

Comment: At that line you are removing the `wait4images` listener of the `ENTER_FRAME` event. Then you do `addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameAdvance,false,0,true);` and it keeps adding children in a loop never being removed